# Java, updating a Jlist after a file is uploaded

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlist

I am wondering if there is a way to update a JList after a file is uploaded to a FTP server.

For example: When I login in, it loads a JList and gets the files. When you upload a file, it uploads but the list does NOT update.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class MyClass{

public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
public static JButton download = new JButton();
public static JButton upload = new JButton();
public static JButton login = new JButton();
public static JButton close = new JButton();
public static JLabel label = new JLabel();
public static JList list = new JList();
public static JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
public static FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
public static JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
public static String[] files;

public static void main(String args[]){

    //JFrame, frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //JPanel, panel
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);

    //JButton, upload
    upload.setBounds(25, 25, 90, 30);
    upload.setText("Upload");

    //JButton, download
    download.setBounds(25, 60, 90, 30);
    download.setText("Download");

    //JButton, login
    login.setBounds(25, 95, 90, 30);
    login.setText("Login");
    panel.add(login);

    //JButton, close
    close.setBounds(25, 95, 90, 30);
    close.setText("Close");

    //JLabel, label
    label.setBounds(25, 435, 500, 20);
    panel.add(label);

    //JList, list


    //Login
    login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Login();
        }

    });

    //Logout and close
    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Close();
        }
    });

    //Upload
    upload.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

              chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
              int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(dialog);
              if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                  label.setText("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
              }else{
                  label.setText("Cancelled");
              }

              Upload();





        }
    });

}



public static void Login(){
      String server = "X";
        int port = X;         //Crossed out for 
        String user = "X";    //Purposes
        String pass = "X";



            try{
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            if(ftpClient.isConnected()){
                label.setText("Connected to: " + server);
                panel.remove(login);
                panel.add(close);
                panel.add(upload);
                panel.add(download);

                files = ftpClient.listNames();

                list = new JList(files); //data has type Object[]
                list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
                list.setVisibleRowCount(20);

                list.setLayout(null);
                list.setBounds(130, 25, 340, 400);
                panel.add(list);
                frame.repaint();
            }

            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: Can't connect");
            }

}


public static void Close(){

    try{
    ftpClient.logout();
    ftpClient.disconnect();
    System.exit(1);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.exit(1); 
    }

}


public static void Upload(){

       try {

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

            String firstRemoteFile = selectedFile.getName();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);

            label.setText("Uploading...");
            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                label.setText("Finished.");

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 

}

}
```

Comment: The JList doesn't update because you never change the data that it holds. It won't magically change on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JList doesn't update because you never change it. You need to re-load the updated data after the file is uploaded, and this can be done similar to how you load the list with data initially, only you don't want to create a new JList, but rather a new DefaultListModel, one that holds the new data, and then is added to the JList via the JList's `setModel(...)` method.

Other side issues:

- Your code shows a significant over-use of the static modifier, and in fact most all of your methods and fields should be non-static instance fields and methods, as this will help you create less complex and more reusable code.
- You will want to learn and follow Java naming conventions, including giving variables and methods names that start with lower-case letters and classes names that start with upper case letters. Following conventions will make your code more understandable to others, including us.
- You are using null-layouts and setBounds, and this will hamstring your code. Swing GUI's are not built to be pixel-perfect, and use of absolute positioning will mean that your GUI is almost guaranteed to be ugly in all but a few OS's and screen resolutions, and will make your GUI layout very difficult to modify or enhance. It's a common Swing newbie mistake to think that use of null layouts makes GUI creation easier, because in the long run, it's the exact opposite.